# Material UI range sliders total sum 100

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, rangeslider

I have three Material UI sliders denoting percentage values.I want the total of the sliders to be 100 such that the values of sliders adjust automatically to keep total 100. How can that be done?

Comment: I think you can write a hook to watch `value` of 3 sliders and change them automatically

Comment: Hey thanks but I am new to React Hooks can you tell how I can fetch the slider values set in a hook?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to replace the basic inputs with Material-UI sliders.

```
///Slider.js
import React from 'react'

const Slider = ({title, value, onChange}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="slider-container">
        <div className="range-min-max-values">
          <span>{title}</span>
        </div>
        <input
          type="range"
          min={0}
          max={100}
          value={value}
          title={title}
          onChange={onChange}
        />
        <span>{value.toFixed(2)}%</span>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Slider




///Index.js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Slider from './slider'

const data = ['Slider 1', 'Slider 2', 'Slider 3']

function App({sliders}) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(
    new Array(sliders.length).fill(100 / sliders.length),
  )

  function handleChange(index, value) {
    let maxValue = 100
    const remaining = maxValue - parseInt(value, 10)
    setValues((vs) =>
      vs.map((v, i) => {
        if (i === index) return parseInt(value, 10)
        const oldRemaining = maxValue - parseInt(vs[index], 10)
        if (oldRemaining) return (remaining * v) / oldRemaining
        return remaining / (sliders.length - 1)
      }),
    )
  }

  return sliders.map((item, index) => (
    <Slider
      key={index}
      index={index}
      value={values[index]}
      title={item}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e.target.value)}
    />
  ))
}

ReactDOM.render(<App sliders={data} />, document.getElementById('root'))
```